# Filter within a column by date in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, stringr

I have a dataset, df, The Date column consists of dates from December and January. I would like to filter and make a new dataset with dates only from January onward.

```
     Date                         ID


     12/20/2019 1:00:01 AM        A
     12/30/2019 2:00:02 AM        B
     01/01/2020 1:00:00 AM        C
     02/05/2020 2:00:05 AM        D
```

I would like this:

```
   Date                       ID

  01/01/2020 1:00:00 AM        C
  02/05/2020 2:00:05 AM        D
```

Can I use dplyr with this? or Base R

```
    library(lubridate)
    library(tidyverse)

    filter(Date) >= 01-01-2020 ?
```

dput is

```
  structure(list(Date = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("1/1/2020 1:00:00 AM", 
  "12/20/2019 1:00:01 AM", "12/30/2019 2:00:02 AM", "2/5/2020 2:00:05 AM"
  ), class = "factor"), ID = structure(1:4, .Label = c("A", "B", 
 "C", "D"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -4L))
```

Comment: Do you mean: "...consists of dates from December __2019 and onward__?"

Comment: From January 2020 onwards

Comment: I meant in the very first line of your introduction. You said "...consists of dates from December and January". Oh, never mind. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe just `filter` on year and select datest from 2020?

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>% mutate(Date = mdy_hms(Date)) %>% filter(year(Date) >= 2020)

#                 Date ID
#1 2020-01-01 01:00:00  C
#2 2020-02-05 02:00:05  D
```

Or using base R :

```
subset(transform(df, Date = as.POSIXct(Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")), 
                 as.integer(format(Date, "%Y")) >= 2020)
```

Comment: Furthermore,@Ronak, how do filter the dates to only January? Would I put                          filter(year(Date) =  01-01-2020 ?? I don't think this is right?

Comment: Do `df %>% mutate(Date = mdy_hms(Date)) %>% filter(year(Date) >= 2020, month(Date) == 1)`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `subset` with `strptime` in `base R`

```
subset(df1, strptime(Date, "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")$year + 1900 >=2020)
#                 Date ID
#3 1/1/2020 1:00:00 AM  C
#4 2/5/2020 2:00:05 AM  D
```